# when change checkbox before its animation complete gives error "JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION" in API24(Nougat)

Tags: android

I created a scaling animation for my checkbox. When it simply scales up and returns its original size again. It works expected all versions of Android except API 24 (Nougat).(API 25 and 26 not tested)

When I test my app, I tried to produce faults. This time I recognized when I change check before animation complete it gives the error in the below for API 24

```
A/art: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call void android.view.View.setScaleX(float) on null object
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
    art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]     from void android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(java.lang.Object, long, float)
```

I decided to disable checkbox for a while then enable it. But I failed with it, because checkbox is in a viewholder in recyclerview. Changing one checkbox effects others as well. It was not a stable solution.

My CheckBox in a card

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/card_bookmark_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_like_bookmark_size"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/card_checkbox_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/card_bookmark"
            android:button="@null"
            android:checked="false"
            android:gravity="end"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/card_like_checkbox"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,24:32"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/card_like_checkbox"
            android:stateListAnimator="@animator/scale"/>
```

animator/scale

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <set>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueTo="1.5"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:valueTo="1.5"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:valueTo="4dp"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="scaleX"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="scaleY"
        android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:propertyName="translationZ"
        android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:valueTo="0dp"
        android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType" />

        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="1"
            android:valueType="floatType" />

        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueTo="0dp"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I found many great answers in this site but not for this one. Now I am stuck.

Thank you for reading this any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you are removing the object before the animation is complete? I think you should either wait for the animation to end, or stop the animation then.

Comment: @Botje thank you for reply, I dont remove the object any time, it would crash with other versions too if it would be the case.